# PHP Exec hangs when trying to use NodeJS to create a connection to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, exec

I am trying to run the following NodeJS script to create a connection to a MySQL database and perform a few tasks:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "url",
    user: "xxx",
    password: "yyy",
    database: "zzz"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Success");
});
```

When this script is run from an Ubuntu Terminal, it works as expected, but when I try to do the same using the exec function from PHP in the following way:

```
$execString = "/usr/bin/node /home/user/sampleProject/example.js";          
exec($execString, $output);
```

The program hangs, not returning the expected "Success" message.

I enabled and checked the MySQL logs and verified that the database is indeed receiving the request to connect when calling the script using the exec function, but for some reason it never finishes and continues to execute until it times out.

Any ideas or help as to why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Comment: It actually does, if I change the contents of the example.js file to just: console.log("Hello world"); , the exec function does return the "Hello world" string

Comment: Why are you even doing this? PHP can connect directly to your database if that's what you need

Comment: I'm doing this because, I'm working with some pretty large JSON strings and I need to do a lot of substitutions and merges using those strings, but so far I haven't been able to get a decent enough speed in performing those tasks, using plain PHP and a few libraries that are supposed to help with that

Comment: Are you trying to do string manipulation directly on those objects or are you decoding the JSON into an object/array and then manipulating it that way? The latter is normally a more effective approach. And is node significantly faster at that? And what does any of that have to do with mysql? Is the data held in the database? Anyway I'd suspect maybe, if the code above by itself causes the error, that the fact the connection code is async and causes a callback might be a problem for the exec method.

Comment: I've tried both the object and array approaches in PHP, but in the tests that I've done, it takes PHP around 25 min vs 2 min in Node to perform the same algorithm. I won't say it's PHP's fault (it probably has to do with some implementation details on my part), but so far it has been much quicker using Node. The JSON strings are stored in a MySQL database. That last part actually makes a lot of sense, it would be cool if there was some trick to work around that

Comment: Well, do you definitely need to trigger this via PHP? Any reason you can't call the node script directly? How is it being triggered - is it part of a bigger PHP script, or just a small script called from a browser, or what?

Comment: The idea that I had in mind was to call the script as a of a function that is called everytime an API endpoint is invoked

Comment: Well node can function as an API endpoint directly just as well as PHP can

Comment: A smart person that you are, you're right, I could just use that same script code as an API endpoint in Node, and call one API from another, thank you, sadly I can only upvote your comments and not give you more reputation points

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I wrote it up as an answer, below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suspect, if the code above by itself causes the error, that the fact the connection code is async and causes a callback might be a problem for the exec method.

But...do you definitely need to trigger this via PHP? NodeJS can function as an API endpoint directly just as well as PHP can. You could expose that directly, rather than going via PHP. Or at least expose it as an endpoint, and then call it via HTTP from PHP.